# HTML/Javascript Button Click Counter

Tags: javascript, html, click, counter

I have done something similar to this before, and I know this is really close. I'm just trying to make it so that my button increments the javascript variable, and the function then displays the new value.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    int clicks = 0;
    function click() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onClick="click()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

Comment: i think the value of int clicks is always 0, you aren't getting the value from the screen before you increment

Comment: @DhavalMarthak but in this case he uses `getElementById()` appropriately.

Comment: @Monacraft Edited just a min ago :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use `var` instead of `int` for your `clicks` variable generation and `onClick` instead of `click` as your function name:

```js
var clicks = 0;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click me</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>
```

In JavaScript variables are declared with the `var` keyword. There are no tags like `int`, `bool`, `string`... to declare variables. You can get the type of a variable with 'typeof(yourvariable)', more support about this you find on Google.

And the name 'click' is reserved by JavaScript for function names so you have to use something else.

Comment: At Least provide a better explanation, otherwise great answer: +1.

Answer (score 10):

Don't use the word "click" as the function name. It's a reserved keyword in JavaScript. In the bellow code I’ve used "hello" function instead of "click"

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Space Clicker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var clicks = 0;
    function hello() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    </script>
    <button type="button" onclick="hello()">Click me</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at the code you're having typos, here is the updated code

```
var clicks = 0; // should be var not int
    function clickME() {
        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks; //getElementById() not getElementByID() Which you corrected in edit
 }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/z66WF/)

**Note:** Don't use in-built handlers, as `.click()` is javascript function try giving different name like  `clickME()`

Comment: Thankyou, I'm pretty sure that it was the var that fixed it.

Comment: And the name of the function and that typo in `getElementById`

Comment: @Jumpoy NO, You should rename `click()` to `someOther()` :)

Answer (score 1):

Through this code, you can get click count on a button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Button</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/button.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <button id="btn" class="btnst" onclick="myFunction()">0</button>
</body>
</html>
 ----------JAVASCRIPT----------
let count = 0;
function myFunction() {
  count+=1;
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = count;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
     var clicks = 0;
    function myFunction() {

        clicks += 1;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = clicks;


    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This should work for you :) Yes **var** should be used

Comment: This is genius - I was trying to make a vote counter, and this works brilliantly (all I had to add to it was to disable use after onclick).