# Make a button only do something after a certain number of clicks?

Tags: html, button, click

Is there a way to make a button completely useless until a certain amount of clicks have been performed in HTML?

For example, a button that doesn't do anything when clicked until it has been clicked 100 times.
On the 100th click it links to a separate page saying "Congratulations! You found a secret page!"

Comment: set a counter on click

Comment: You could do that, but not with HTML.  you will have to use javascript or jQuery for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/Javascript Button Click Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402777/html-javascript-button-click-counter)

Comment: maintain click counts in a counter variable and check if it exceeds the threshold on each click

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to increment on click and at certain click you can run the functionality you want

```js
var count = 0;

function a() {
  count++;
  if (count == 3)
    alert("pressed 3 times")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="a()">click me 3 times</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this to move to the other page by clicking 100 times.**

```
var count = 0;


function func() {
count++;
 if (count == 100)
("#butn").href("your link here");
   }
 <button id="butn" onclick="func()"></button>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.