# How to add another event with a second click and a third click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

After a few hours of trial and error I put my post here with a question, maybe one of you will be able to help me. I've created a function that is called with the "onclick" attribute after clicking on the button. This function changes font size in selected elements of the page. I would like to add a different percentage, e.g. 200% at second click on the button. I'd appreciate any help.

JS code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("increase-size").addEventListener("click", increasSize);

function increasSize() {
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, input, a");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.fontSize = "150%";
  }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<button type="button" class="increase-size" onclick="increasSize()"></button>
```

I tried to solve it with a counter, but I failed.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("increase-size").addEventListener("click", increaseSize);

var counter = 0;

function increaseSize() {
  counter += 1;
  var x = document.querySelector("html");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(counter == 1) {
      x[i].style.fontSize = "150%";
    } else if (counter == 2) {
      x[i].style.fontSize = "200%";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your counter gets reset every time your function is called. Declare it outside of the function and access it within your function. You can then increase your counter with `counter++` at the end of your function. Also, please note your function is misnamed `increasSize` instead of `increaseSize` ("e" before "Size"). Works fine but it's good to avoid typos like that to easily reference the function somewhere else without having to dig back to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Counter seems like a good option. I found this [HTML/Javascript Button Click Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402777/html-javascript-button-click-counter) may be make sure its a global variable and it should work ?

Answer (score 0):

make some global variables

```
fontSizes = ['100%', '150%', '200%'];
selectedFontSizeIndex = 0;
```

Then in your click function:

```
function increaseSize() {
  selectedFontSizeIndex++;
  selectedFontSizeIndex = selectedFontSize % fontSizes.length;
  var x = document.querySelector("html");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.fontSize = fontSizes[selectedFontSizeIndex];
  }
}
```

This will continue to loop through your options. Let me know if any of the lines of code need more explanation

Comment: Sorry, but I'm getting that message: ```ReferenceError: selectedFontSize is not defined```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems:

1. `increase-size` should be the `id` instead of the `class` and called as `document.getElementById("increase-size")`. Otherwise, you can use it as `document.getElementsByClassName("increase-size")[0]` since it returns a list of elements.
2. The `click` function should be passed the `function` name only, otherwise, it will be called twice:

```
<button type="button" class="increase-size" onclick="increasSize"></button>
```

3. `counter` should be a global variable and `incremented` in every call. The way it is used here is set to zero every time the function is used.
4. You do not need the `for loop`.
5. It is a better practice not to have typos in function names: rename it to `increaseSize`.
6. You only need to set the listener once, either in the `html` or `JavaScript`. It is better to leave the `js` part.

The final solution is as follows:

```js
document.getElementById("increase-size").addEventListener("click", increaseSize);
let counter = 0;
function increaseSize() {
  console.log(counter);
  counter++;
  var x = document.querySelector("html");
  if(counter == 1) {
      x.style.fontSize = "150%";
  } else if (counter == 2) {
      x.style.fontSize = "200%";
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<button type="button" id="increase-size">Increase</button>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>World</h2>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I be so wrong?

TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: These are not all problems but bad practices in general. Make sure you change the class to the id if you want to use it like this, and place the script at the end of your body.

Comment: I also have another bug that makes the function not work. ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration `counter' before initialization

Comment: Unfortunately, but it doesn't work for me. Probably because of those mistakes. Nevertheless, thanks to this answer I learned something new about js.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by make a simple switch using a boolean that will increase and decrease font-size upon clicking the button. 
Here is how it will work

```
    var swit=true
      document.getElementById("increase-size").addEventListener(click, ()=>{
  function increasSize() {
  //150%
  if(swit){
  var x = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, input, a");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.fontSize = "150%";
    }
    swit=false
    return
  }
  // 200%
  if (!swit){

  var x = document.querySelectorAll("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, input, a");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.fontSize = "200%";
    }
    swit=true
    return
  }
  }
   increasSize() 

  });
```