# JavaScript-limited click count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a problem with limited click counter using JavaScript. I have tried suggestions below but it seems like my problem might be somewhere else.

[HTML/Javascript Button Click Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402777/html-javascript-button-click-counter)

Basically I want to count clicks x times, which is provided from `<input type="number">` field. It looks like the script is not recognizing this item in counting function.

Below I'd like to share example code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var count = 0;
  var number = document.getElementById("amount").value;
  var btn = document.getElementById("clickme");
  var disp = document.getElementById("clicked");
  btn.onclick = function() {
    count++;
    disp.innerHTML = count;
  }
  if (count > number) {
    btn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>


  <input type="number" id="amount">
  <p>how many times button should be clicked</p>

  <p>Click the button.</p>
  <div id="clicked"></div>

  <button id="clickme" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


  <script>
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the surrounding function and the `onclick` attribute.
Also, move the value retrieval and the disabled logic inside the listener, and convert the value to a number:

```js
let count = 0;
const btn = document.getElementById("clickme");
const disp = document.getElementById("clicked");
const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
btn.onclick = function () {
    count++;
    disp.innerHTML = count;
    const number = +amount.value;
    if (count > number) {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="amount" >
<p>how many times button should be clicked</p>

<p>Click the button.</p>
<div id="clicked"></div>

<button id="clickme">Click me</button>
```

Comment: I think you want `if (count >= number) {` because right now if I enter 2, I am able to click it 3 times before the button gets disabled.

Comment: Yes maybe, I just copied the question's condition

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something like this. The `limit` can be increased or decreased at any time to allow for more or less clicks. Once it reaches `0`, the button will stop adding to the `count`  -

```js
const f =
  document.forms.myapp

function update (event) {
  const limit = Number(f.limit.value)
  if (limit <= 0) return 
  f.limit.value = limit - 1
  f.count.value = Number(f.count.value) + 1
}

f.mybutton.addEventListener("click", update)
```

```html
<form id="myapp">
  <input type="number" name="limit" value="10">
  <button type="button" name="mybutton">click me</button>
  <output name="count">0</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply your solution using the snippet below.

```js
let count = 0;
const inp = document.getElementById("amount");
const countEl = document.getElementById("clicked");


function myFunction(e) {
  if (++count >= Number(inp.value)) e.target.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="amount">
<p>How many times button should be clicked</p>
<p>Click the button.</p>
<button id="clickme" onclick="myFunction(event)">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to count the click events with the limit provided by `<input type="number">` field and adding data to the array. Additioanlly, I am trying to decrease dynamically the amount of click events and remove last records from array using another button. Basically I have NAN value when I try to get counter value to decrease it.
It looks like this:
HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <input type="number" id="amount">
  <p>how many times button should be clicked</p>
 <p> Add question</p> <input type="text" id="question">
  <p>Click the button.</p>
  <div id="clicked"></div>

  <button id="clickme" >add me</button>
  <button id="delme">
  delete me
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```
var count = 0;
var i=0;
const btn = document.getElementById("clickme");
const disp = document.getElementById("clicked");
var amount = document.getElementById("amount");
var question = document.getElementById("question");
var tab;
btn.onclick = function () {
    count++;
    disp.innerHTML = count;
    var number = +amount.value;
    tab=new Array(number);
    
   tab[i]=question.value;
    console.log(tab[i] + i);
    question.value=" ";
    i++;
    
    if (count == number) {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}

var delbtn=document.getElementById("delme");
var countdown = parseInt(document.getElementById("clicked"));

delbtn.onclick = function () {
    console.log(countdown);
    countdown--;
    disp.innerHTML = countdown;
    
    if (countdown == 0) {
        btn.disabled = true;
    }
}
```